# Minified Enums resulted an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a TypeScript with 2 enums (Fig 2). When launchSettings.json (Fig 4) with "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" in the profile, the app runs without problem. When changes to "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production" and with js minified (Fig 3), the app will get a browser error (Fig 1) saying

Fig 1:

```html
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'"
```

Fig 2: enum.js

```ts
export enum EnumGetControlValueBehavior{
  Elaborated,
  Simple
}

export enum EnumChangeEventArg {
  Ready,
  Change,
  NoScroll
}
```

Fig 3: minimized enum.js that causes the error

```js
var n,t;export*;(function(n){n[n.Elaborated=0]="Elaborated";n[n.Simple=1]="Simple"})(n||(n={}));export*;(function(n){n[n.Ready=0]="Ready";n[n.Change=1]="Change";n[n.NoScroll=2]="NoScroll"})(t||(t={}))
```

Fig 4: launchSettings.json

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:30667",
      "sslPort": 44381
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess",
      "use64Bit": true,
      "jsWebView2Debugging": true
    },
    "IPRehab": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "jsWebView2Debugging": true,
      "sqlDebugging": false,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"browser error"_... in which browser?

Comment: in Edge browser

Comment: Where is _"js minification as shown in Fig 3"_?

Comment: sorry about that.  see the correction.  Fig 3 is the last line.

Comment: What does your production configuration look like?

Comment: do you mean web.config, startup.cs, and/or launchSettings.json?  The only difference in launchSettings.json is ""environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"}